# Problem with Azure Api and ChatGPT (python)

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I was given the task to deal with the Azure OpenAI Service and ChatGPT. In the process, when they gave me the keys, endpoint, etc., I ran into this problem:

```
openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = <PATH>'. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details.
```

Here is code:

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15" 
openai.api_base = os.getenv("EndPointHERE")
openai.api_key = os.getenv("KeyHere")

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    engine="KSUAI", 
    messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "Assistant is a large language model trained by OpenAI."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who were the founders of Microsoft?"}
    ]
)

print(response)

print(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
```

Comment: `os.getenv()` will return None if the variable is not found in the environment.  So it seems like `openai.api_key` was assigned the value None.

Comment: How are you setting those variables in the environment?

Comment: @JohnGordon This code is taken from the official Microsoft docks, that is not mine. And what, in this case, needs to be done to "declare in the environment" this data and use it further? Just put them in variables and then pass the name of the variables to os.getenv?

Comment: The "official Microsoft docs" assume that you have properly set the environment variable.  This is a configuration/environment issue, not a code issue.

Comment: How to set the environment variable depends on how exactly you are running this code, which you have not shared.

Comment: @JohnGordon The example gives the code that I run in my IDE, only in place of EndPointHERE was written the endpoint taken from Azure, the same with KeyHere

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by removing os.getenv from the code, and writing the given keys and endpoint directly into a variable

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue so I removed 'dotenv' stuff and directly hardcoded the keys into the code but its not ideal method.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = '***********************'
openai.api_base = '******************' 
openai.api_type = 'azure'
openai.api_version = '2023-05-15' 
deployment_name = 'Engine or deployment name on which model is deployed'  

prompt_in = "give your prompt here + input "
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine=deployment_name,
    prompt=prompt_in,
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=200,
    top_p=0.5,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    best_of=1,
    stop=None)
```

you can also use langchain for prompt and for running model.
I hope it will help...!